# RPM meter fluctuates while car speed decreasing or sudden break applications

Tags: hyundai, i20

Recently i had a issue with 2012 model diesel.

while driving rmp meter stands fixed. but while getting down or sudden break application then RPM meter fluctuates and drops to 0. engine goes shut. after engine off car starts normally as-usual. please kindly help any suggestions to take any action.

Comment: Look for a loose electrical connection.,

Comment: What car? What engine? I would advise to monitor the rail (if equipped) pressure. Are there any CEL codes?

Comment: Is the battery held down properly and are the main battery connections clean and tight?  It's possible sudden deceleration is causing the vehicle to loose electrical power, as @SolarMike suggests